# What is the difference between action and target of post?

Tags: html, forms, attributes

I looked for attribute of form on [W3S - HTML Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) page and I saw that, there are two similar attributes, at least I suppose that. I don't understand differences between them. So I want to ask, What is the difference between action and target of post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`action` is where the data is sent, `target` is which window (or tab, frame, iframe) to use for the request. If `action` is omitted, it assumed to be the current page (the same URL). If `target` is omitted, it is assumed to be the same window (or tab).

Using `target="_blank"` always opens in a new window (or tab, frame, iframe). You can use a name for the window so that all links/forms with `target="karl"` would always open in the same window or tab.

This is the actual (current) HTML5 standard information on the `form` element: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-form-element